# Why are SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_CHANGEREQ and SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK the same value?

Tags: ssh, rfc

Reading the RFC about the SSHv2 service `ssh-userauth` I've found two message types that seem to have the same value but are used in different (but similar) situations.

These two values are:

```
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK     60 # RFC 4252 section 7
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_CHANGEREQ 60 # RFC 4252 section 8
```

These values are used during user authentication, the first by the `publickey` auth method to acknowledge a proper authentication using Public Keys. The second value is used by the `password` auth method to tell the client their password has expired or that a password change attempt was not acceptable (password too short, etc...).  Given that these two message types have the same value and are returned by the server how is the client supposed to tell the difference between the two messages?

If the client starts authentication using both `publickey` and `password` methods and receives one or two messages with a message code of `60` what is the expected behavior of the client? Or is multiple concurrent different auth method attempts disallowed by the protocol?

Link to the relevant RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter. The client tries its authorization methods in sequence. The client may batch up and send a bunch of authorization requests without waiting, but the server will reply to them sequentially in the order they were sent.

Comment: I believe you, but could you link to the relevant section of the RFC that says servers must respond sequentially to auth requests?

Comment: "5.1 The client MAY send several authentication requests without waiting for responses from previous requests.  The server MUST process each request completely and acknowledge any failed requests with a SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE message before processing the next request."